# Commiting changes in nested git subtrees

Tags: git, nested, git-submodules, git-subtree

I have been reading a lot on git subtrees as an alternative submodules and was wondering what is the best way to handle nested subtrees with regards to committing changes:

Say you have project A with a subproject B as a subtree (so A is the parent). 
 If I make changes to B while working in A, I need to use **git subtree push** to push the changes onto B. 
Similarly, If I make changes to B whilst working in B, to bring these updates in A I need to use **git subtree pull**

My question is how do you handle committing changes if you add another subproject C which is a subtree in B (ie B is the parent of C). As far as I understand, the below is how you would do it. Is there a better way?

So say you are working in project A and then make changes to C. In order to bring these changes to C, you need to use **git subtree push** twice:
 
1. **Git subtree push** from A to B, then 
2. **Git subtree push** from B to C

Similiary, the reverse is true when making changes in C whilst working within C and **git subtree pull**

This is a bit repetitive, so I was wondering if there is another way to go about it. Perhaps a better way  would to not use subtrees at all? If not, what would be an alternative?